# Not able to see the plug-in in GIMP after placing it in the plug-ins folder

Tags: 16.04, python, plugins, gimp

I have installed GIMP2.10 in my Ubuntu 16.04. I have the following simple plug-in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Tutorial available at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmb-0KcgXzI
# Feedback welcome: jacksonbates@hotmail.com

from gimpfu import *

def sample_plugin(image, drawable):
    # function code goes here...
    print("hello")


register(
    "python-fu-sample_plugin",
    "SHORT DESCRIPTION",
    "LONG DESCRIPTION",
    "Jackson Bates", "Jackson Bates", "2015",
    "sample_plugin",
    "", # type of image it works on (*, RGB, RGB*, RGBA, GRAY etc...)
    [
        # basic parameters are: (UI_ELEMENT, "variable", "label", Default)
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Input layer", None)
        # PF_SLIDER, SPINNER have an extra tuple (min, max, step)
        # PF_RADIO has an extra tuples within a tuple:
        # eg. (("radio_label", "radio_value), ...) for as many radio buttons
        # PF_OPTION has an extra tuple containing options in drop-down list
        # eg. ("opt1", "opt2", ...) for as many options
        # see ui_examples_1.py and ui_examples_2.py for live examples
    ],
    [],
    sample_plugin, menu="<Image>/Filters")  # second item is menu location

main()
```

I saved this as a .py file and placed it at /home//.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins

This folder path is already listed in Edit->Preferences->Folders->Plug-ins

When I restart GIMP, I'm not able to find this sample_plugin in the Filters menu. Not able to understand why. This is my first GIMP plug-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check the file permissions for the plugin file?

try

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/gimp/2.10/plug-ins/YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE_NAME.py
```

replace "YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE_NAME" with your actual file name.

Also check where GIMP is installed, it is installed by default in the location /usr/lib/gimp/2.10/plug-ins/ where 2.10 is the GIMP version

Comment: No, you don't install plugins you are writing in `/usr`. You install them in the `plug-ins` folder of your user profile (or any directory you added in the preferences). In addition the OP is using the flatpak version, which has a different directory structure.

Comment: Oh thanks! I started gimp from command line, python is not able to find the module named gimpfu. I had to make it an executable and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. the python file must have the executable flag
2. you can start Gimp in a terminal and look for Python syntax error messages

Likely 1) since it works for me. But 2) is a good idea anyway since you will see your `print` output there, which is useful when you debug. Since you used `print()`, a word of caution: Gimp uses Python 2.7 and not 3.x, and since you are in a flatpak the Python runtime isn't the one you have installed for your system (so stuff you installed via `pip install` or `apt install python-*` won't be there and you'll have to reinstall them for the flatpak environment).

Comment: Oh thanks! I started gimp from command line, python is not able to find the module named gimpfu. I had to make it an executable and it worked.